# Reset a Cytoscape Graph

Tags: cytoscape.js

I just observed that there are too many questions regarding resetting a cytoscape.js graph to its originally loaded state.

Following is a simple function you need to call to reset the graph:

```
cy.layout();
```

You can bind it to click events as and when needed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset to original state:

```
cy.layout();
```

To fit the randomly panned/zoomed graph to the div:

```
cy.fit();
```

Hope it helps!